# Display selection in the middle of an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText whose visible height is ca. 20 lines.
The app puts some text into it which contains ca. 100 lines.
After that it selects a word or a sentence in this text. The problem is that the selected piece is shown at the bottom but I want it to be shown in the middle of the visible area of the EditText.

Here is how it looks now

[image]

But I want it so

[image]

Here is what I've tried:

```
public void setSelection(final int start, final int end) {
        view.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                chunkBegin = Math.max(0, start - 700);
                chunkEnd = end;

                String text = model.getText().substring(chunkBegin, Math.min(model.getText().length() - 1, chunkEnd + 700));

                view.getTextArea().removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                view.getTextArea().setText(text, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                view.getTextArea().addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

                view.getTextArea().requestFocus();
                final int startSel = start - chunkBegin;
                final int endSel = chunkEnd - chunkBegin;
                view.getTextArea().setSelection(startSel, endSel);

                int height = view.getTextArea().getHeight();
                view.getTextArea().scrollTo(0, height / 2);
            }
        });
    }
```

I thought that the call of `scrollTo()` would achieve it, but it still looked like at the first screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've accomplished it.

The approach with call of `scrollTo()` was right, but the parameters were wrong. I had to determine the current line number and its y-position in pixels. After that I could calculate the right position for scrolling. The whole procedure is implemented in the last five lines.

The final solution is below in case someone needs it too:

```
public void setSelection(final int start, final int end) {
    view.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            chunkBegin = Math.max(0, start - 700);
            chunkEnd = Math.min(model.getText().length() - 1, end + 700);

            String text = model.getText().substring(chunkBegin, chunkEnd);

            view.getTextArea().removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
            view.getTextArea().setText(text, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            view.getTextArea().addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

            view.getTextArea().requestFocus();
            final int startSel = Math.min(view.getTextArea().getText().length(), start - chunkBegin);
            final int endSel = Math.min(view.getTextArea().getText().length(), startSel + end - start);

            view.getTextArea().setSelection(startSel, endSel);

            Layout layout = view.getTextArea().getLayout();

            int selectedLine = layout.getLineForOffset(startSel);
            int currentLineTop = view.getTextArea().getLayout().getLineTop(selectedLine);
            int visibleAreaHeight = view.getTextArea().getHeight();
            view.getTextArea().scrollTo(0, currentLineTop - visibleAreaHeight / 2);
        }
    });
}
```